# Regex or loop in loop

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a function: bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars) which get 2 strings and checks if one of the letters in one string is in the other string.

Here's the code:

```
    public static bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars)
    {
        foreach (char ch in str1)
        {
            foreach (char ch2 in validchars)
            {
                if (ch == ch2)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Other way to write it by using regex:

```
public static bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(str1, @"[" + validchars + "]");
}
```

Which way should I use? (efficient)

Comment: Run many times and measure the performance?

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Got it, it's not hard to measure it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Regex.IsMatch` has too much overhead, I would use `Enumerable.Any`:

```
static bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars)
{
    return str1.Any(c => validChars.Contains(c));
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use "Any" than "IsMatch"... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using linq:

```
public static bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars)
  {
    return str1.Any(ch => validchars.Any(ch2 => ch == ch2));
  }
```

Or

```
public static bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars)
  {
    return (from ch in str1 from ch2 in validchars where ch == ch2 select ch).Any();
  }
```

Comment: Or `validchars.Any(c2 => str1.Any(c1 => c1 == c2));`

Answer (score 1):

Just a variation to the other answers: I would switch str1 and validChars in the check, and also change the type of validChars to IEnumerable as to make it more reusable. Also, making it an extension method makes sense.

```
    static bool ContainsOneOf(this string str1, IEnumerable<char> validchars)
    {
        return validchars.Any(c => str1.Contains(c));
    }
```

Comment: It looks better than using regex

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers posted so far:

```
 public static bool ContainsOneOf(string str1, string validchars)
 {
    return str1.IndexOfAny(validchars.ToCharArray()) != -1;
 }
```

More on `String.IndexOfAny`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx